# Illegal arguments: undefined, string (bcrypt)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I got this error:

```
Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string
    at Object.bcrypt.hashSync (C:\Users\Shair\Desktop\fastly-api\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:189:19)
    at C:\Users\Shair\Desktop\fastly-api\src\routes\user.js:65:29
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Shair\Desktop\fastly-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Shair\Desktop\fastly-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Shair\Desktop\fastly-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Shair\Desktop\fastly-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Shair\Desktop\fastly-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Shair\Desktop\fastly-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Shair\Desktop\fastly-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\Shair\Desktop\fastly-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
```

My user.js

```js
const router = require('express').Router()
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const mysql = require('../dbconfig')
const { auth, admin, restaurant, client } = require('../middleware')
const { login, detail, add, dlt, edit } = require('../model/user')

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body

  mysql.execute(login, [username], (err, result, field) => {
    if (result.length > 0) {
      if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, result[0].password)) {
        const id_user = result[0].id
        const roles = result[0].role_id
        const auth = jwt.sign({ username, id_user, roles }, process.env.APP_KEY)
        const token = auth
        const is_revoked = 0
        const created_on = new Date()
        const updated_on = new Date()
        const revoked = `INSERT INTO revoked_token (token,is_revoked,created_on,updated_on) VALUES (?,?,?,?)`
        mysql.execute(revoked, [token, is_revoked, created_on, updated_on], (err, result, field) => {
          res.send({
            succes: true,
            auth
          })
        })
      } else {
        res.send({
          succes: false,
          msg: "Incorret Password"
        })
      }
    } else {
      res.send({
        succes: false,
        msg: "Username Not Found"
      })
    }
  })
})

router.get('/logout', auth, (req, res) => {
  const token = req.headers.auth_token
  const sql = 'UPDATE revoked_token SET is_revoked=? WHERE token=?'
  mysql.execute(sql, [1, token], (err, result, field) => {
    res.send({
      success: true, data: result, msg: "Log Out Success"
    })
    console.log(err)
  })
})

router.post('/registuser', (req, res) => {
  const { name, username, password } = req.body
  const role_id = 3
  const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
  const enc_pass = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)
  const created_on = new Date()
  const updated_on = new Date()

  const check = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=?'
  mysql.execute(check, [username], (err1, res1, field1) => {
    if (err1) {
      console.log(err1)
      res.send({
        status: 400,
        msg: err1,
      })
    } else if (res1.length === 0) {
      const sql = 'INSERT INTO user(name, username, password, role_id, created_on, updated_on) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)'
      mysql.execute(sql, [name, username, enc_pass, role_id, created_on, updated_on], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          res.send({ succsess: true, data: result })
        }
      })
    }
    else {
      res.send({
        status: 400,
        msg: 'Username already used.',
      })
    }
  })
})

router.put('/forgotpassword', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body
  const updated_on = new Date()
  const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
  const enc_pass = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)
  const sql = `UPDATE user SET password = ?, updated_on = ? where username = ?`
  mysql.execute(sql, [enc_pass, username, updated_on], (err, result, field) => {
    res.send({ succcess: true, data: result })
  })
})

router.post('/', auth, admin, (req, res) => {
  const { name, username, password, role_id } = req.body
  const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
  const enc_pass = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)
  const created_on = new Date()
  const updated_on = new Date()

  mysql.execute(
    add, [name, username, enc_pass, role_id, created_on, updated_on],
    (err, result, field) => {
      res.send(result)
      console.log(err)
    }
  )
})

router.post('/registrest', restaurant, (req, res) => {
  const { name, username, password } = req.body
  const role_id = 2
  const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
  const enc_pass = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)
  const created_on = new Date()
  const updated_on = new Date()

  const sql = 'INSERT INTO user(name, username, password, role_id, created_on, updated_on) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)'
  mysql.execute(sql, [name, username, enc_pass, role_id, created_on, updated_on], (err, result) => {
    res.send({ succsess: true, data: result })
  })
})

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params

  mysql.execute(detail, [id], (err, result, field) => {
    res.send({ succes: true, data: result[0] })
  })
})

router.delete('/:id', auth, admin, (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params
  mysql.execute(dlt, [id], (err, result, field) => {
    res.send({ succes: true, data: result })
    console.log(err)
  })
})

router.put('/:id', auth, admin, (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params
  const { name, username, password, role_id } = req.body
  const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
  const enc_pass = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)
  const updated_on = new Date()

  mysql.execute(
    edit, [name, username, enc_pass, role_id, updated_on, id], (err, result, field) => {
      res.send({ succes: true, data: result })
      console.log(err)
    }
  )
})

module.exports = router
```

I got these errores when I try to post the localhost:3000/user/registuser url with postman

I've learned bcrypt has two ways to work, one is async and sync, I decide to use sync, may be that is the problem?
I'm using: bcryptjs", "body-parser", "cors", "dotenv", "express", "express-paginate", "jsonwebtoken","multer","mysql2", "nodemailer", "path"

Comment: You are not sending the `password` in the `/registeruser` endpoint probably. Check how are you consuming the endpoint.

Comment: this is a screenshort of my postman https://prnt.sc/rhgutl, and Im sure Im sending correctly password, check here https://prnt.sc/rhgv9r

Comment: do you have `bodyParser()` middleware used for your express app?

Comment: No, I don't. How to add it?